# How do I implement a basic menu navigation system with Three20?

Tags: iphone, three20

I'm trying to get started with Three20 and just want to get a basic menu navigation system going. I'm looking for a way to create menu that's just a list view with static text. Selecting an item should be able to move to another menu or a different view controller.

Looking at the documentation for Three20, I'm a bit confused by the need for data sources and models. How do I just create something simple, without the need to connect to the Internet to get the data to populate a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three20 provides a sample app that does exactly this. Check out the [TTNavigatorDemo](http://github.com/facebook/three20/tree/122b14a4662a51ed508d543747b26b6f1d8da79f/samples/TTNavigatorDemo) code on github.

The key concept to grasp is the [+(TTSectionedDataSource *) dataSourceWithObjects:](http://api.three20.info/interface_t_t_sectioned_data_source.html#a756f7f746e49ed15b2bbe4399c9f49d6) method. It lets you define a list of strings instead of subsclassing TTSectionedDataSource.